# why would one want to write embedded assembly code?

Tags: assembly, arm

I've recently started embedded programming on ARM platform, and I've seen in several code samples that despite they have written the project in C language, in some places between the code they call some assembly functions that they have written themselves. the more surprising thing is that all they do in that assembly function is to `mov smth, smth_else`. since the codes have been written by some professional teams, I wonder what is the benefit of doing this?

**UPDATE**
In my limited observations, I've just thought that this practice is so ubiquitous that it doesn't need an example, But it seems that it's not the case. So this is one of the examples I've mentioned:

```
 /**
 * @brief  Return the Process Stack Pointer
 *
 * @param  none
 * @return uint32_t ProcessStackPointer
 *
 * Return the actual process stack pointer
 */
uint32_t __get_PSP(void) __attribute__( ( naked ) );
uint32_t __get_PSP(void)
{
  uint32_t result=0;

  __ASM volatile ("MRS %0, psp\n\t" 
                  "MOV r0, %0 \n\t"
                  "BX  lr     \n\t"  : "=r" (result) );
  return(result);
}
```

This is one part of `CMSIS Cortex-M3 Core Peripheral Access Layer Source File`. Still, I can't understand why would one want to `branch` using `BX` and not a simple function call or goto in C.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: You can't make a `mrs` (Move to ARM register from system coprocessor register) call via C except using inline assembly, that's why you need to use assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of obvious reasons why you might see assembler in a project - particularly an embedded one:

- Performance: Optimising for the features of specific hardware.  You'll typically see this in codecs, CPU intensive DSP operations (for instance, DFT),  implementations of some C standard library functions (e.g. `memcpy`).
- Reaching places a C compiler can't: Typically a few very specialist close-to-the-metal situation in the implementation of operating systems such as initialisation code, context switch, interrupt handlers. synchronisation operations.

Comment: You do not need ASM for performance though if the embedded architecture supports SIMD, VLIW, and other fancy things, but yeah, it is not available everywhere and even if they were, there is still probably some place for optimization due to the compiler shortcomings as we do not live in an ideal world. :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp If anything, SIMD units are less amenable to optiomisations than regular processors simply because some of the operations are not easily concisely expressed in C or C++. Hand-coded implementations of DSP operations and codecs are quite commonplace.

Comment: You have missed an inevitable use of assembly - system calls which generally wrapped in standard libraries. In arm world that's `svc` (supervisor call).